# Spring Data JPA - Entity with FetchTyp.Lazy how to split Query?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

iam using Spring data JPA with Hibernate and the Problem is that i want to get The Users with Roles and without Roles (He should not Join in Database). How can i do that? FetchType is LAZY.

my User class:

```
public class APPUser implements UserDetails{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String username;
    
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = APPUserRoles.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable( 
            name = "APPUserRoles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn (name = "username", referencedColumnName = "username")
        )
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private List<APPUserRoles> appuserroles;
```

And my Repository for Spring data:

```
    @Query("SELECT user FROM APPUser user JOIN FETCH user.appuserroles WHERE user.username :username")
    APPUser findByUsername(@Param("username") String username); // WITH JOIN because of @Query
    
    APPUser findByUsername(String username); // Wihtout Join because LAZY
```

Now i want to get ONLY the Users (he should not do a JOIN). and on the other side i want to get Users WITH Roles?

so in my example above you see that so i need two same Methods but in one Case WITH JOIN and on other case WITHOUT join.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Your code looks good. The methods must have different names of course. Like findByUsername() vs. loadFullByUsername()